# Transforming rows into columns with Analytic functions in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table

| Date | Price | Customer | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 100 | 1 | A |
| 2021 | 100 | 1 | A |
| 2022 | 110 | 1 | A |
| 2020 | 50 | 2 | B |
| 2021 | 80 | 2 | B |

I want to transform my data to see in one row what the price customers pay in this year, i.e. 2022, and last year, i.e. 2021, and calculate its delta. If a customer did not have a transaction in 2022, I want to exclude them from my output.

So the result should look like:

| CY | Price_CY | PY | Price_PY | Customer | Product | Price_Delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 110 | 2021 | 100 | 1 | A | 1.1 |

I am thinking I need to self join and use a window function, but not sure how to approach it?

Comment: Self join is the right track, you dont' need a window function. Just filter one table for year 2022 and the other for 2021. while matching same customer and product.

Answer (score 1):

If you want current year and previous year relative to the current date (not for each input year), then you may filter input by two years and then pivot it:

> ```
> select
>   cy, cy_price,
>   py, py_price,
>   cy_price/py_price as delta,
>   customer_id,
>   product
> from (
>   select *
>   from test_tab
>   --reduce input
>   where dt in (
>     extract(year from sysdate),
>     extract(year from sysdate) - 1
>   )
> )
> pivot(
>   max(price) as price,
>   max(dt)
>   for dt in (
>     2022 as cy,
>     2021 as py
>   )
> )
> where cy is not null
>   --there's something for this year
> ```

> | CY | CY_PRICE | PY | PY_PRICE | DELTA | CUSTOMER_ID | PRODUCT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022 | 110 | 2021 | 100 | 1.1 | 1 | A |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=60d51a032632e86dc8e38fe97c7c0ae7)*

Answer (score 0):

You may use `LAG` function with a `CTE` as the following:

```
With CTE As
(
  Select Date_ As CY, Price As Price_CY,
       Lag(Date_) Over (Partition By Customer, Product Order By Date_) As PY,
       Lag(Price) Over (Partition By Customer, Product Order By Date_) As Price_PY,
       Customer, Product,
       Price / Lag(Price) Over (Partition By Customer, Product Order By Date_) As Price_Delta
  From Your_Table
)
Select CY, Price_CY, PY, Price_PY, Customer, Product, Price_Delta
From CTE
Where CY = 2022 And Customer = 1 And Product = 'A'
```

See a demo from *[uk<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c87517561b95024221cfe0398eec4a24)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Conditional Aggregation* along with `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic function while matching the `"Date"` columns values with the values of the last two years such as

```
WITH  t2 AS
(
  SELECT column_value AS year, 
         MAX(CASE WHEN "Date"=column_value THEN price END) AS price, 
         Customer,Product,
         ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER (PARTITION BY Customer,Product ORDER BY column_value DESC) AS rn 
    FROM table(sys.odcinumberlist(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy')-1,TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy')))
   CROSS JOIN t
   GROUP BY column_value, Customer,Product      
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN year END) AS cy,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN price END) AS price_cy,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN year END) AS py,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN price END) AS price_py,
       Customer,Product,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN price END)/
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN price END) AS price_delta
  FROM t2
 GROUP BY Customer,Product    
HAVING NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN price END),0)*
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN price END),0)>0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1ec0a74079721968705956cdd81f01ba)</kbd>